# Unauthorized with client authentication scheme NTLM

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, windows-server-2008

I'm receiving the following error from an ASPX page that is calling a WCF service.

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.

I'm in a load-balanced web server environment, and *only* get the error when the client ASPX page is hitting the WCF service (also on the load-balanced web server) on the *same* server.

For example: 
ASPX page on server A -> WCF service on server B = No issues. 
ASPX page on server B -> WCF service on server C = No issues. 
ASPX page on server B -> WCF service on server B = Error from above.

The servers are IIS 7.5, and the WCF service is currently configured with Anonymous and Windows authentication running as the Network Service account.

Does this have anything to do with loopback protection? I cannot currently replicate these results in a single server environment where the application and service are hosted on the same machine.

Here are my bindings for the ASPX page and the service:

Client:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Imyservice">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://loadbalancedserver/myservice/myservice.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Imyservice"
        contract="myservice.Imyservice" name="BasicHttpBinding_Imyservice" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

WCF Service:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="myservice.Service.myservice">
        <endpoint address="" bindingNamespace="http://services.company.net/myservice"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding"
          contract="myservice.Imyservice" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone runs across this, it *was* due to the IIS loopback issue. Registry fixes from https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37337.disable-loopback-check-in-iis.aspx did the trick.

Comment: I had a windows service running against an https API and was receiving the same message 'unauthorized with scheme ntlm.... only allowed scheme ntlm' and fixed it by applying the DisableLoopBackCheck registry fix which I think used to be linked there but is now linked here. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37337.disable-loopback-check-in-iis.aspx